# How to speed up backend of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

my magento store backend is very slow, how can I speed up admin panel in magento?
I used items in below link but admin panel is still very slow:
https://suyati.com/blog/speed-up-magento-admin-backend/

Answer (score 1):

3 ways to speed up Magento backend:

1. Sign up for better hosting plan. More CPU, More RAM.
2. Audit your server. Make sure it is optimized. Upgrade OS. Upgrade web server (nginx or apache). Fine tune MySQL with the help of [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl).
3. 3rd party plugins audit. Some custom extensions might slow your backend. Disable 3rd party plugins one by one and benchmark speed.

Taken from [here](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-slow-backend).

Bonus point: [enable](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-enable-the-magento-profiler.html) Magento profiler and study its trace. See what function calls take most time. Try to understand why they take that much time and what you can do about. (In most cases it is some custom plugin, just delete it or find an alternative)